# AdColony unity sdk

Tags: sdk, adcolony

Hello I have problem with installing AdColony SDK for Unity. I just setup code like in instruction but it still shows that I haven't any ads in my zone. I have no idea if I did something wrong or I forgot to implement something.

```
public void Initialize()
{
    // Assign any AdColony Delegates before calling Configure
    AdColony.OnV4VCResult = OnV4VCResult;

    // If you wish to use a the customID feature, you should call  that now.
    // Then, configure AdColony:
    AdColony.Configure
    (
        "version:1.0,store:google",// Arbitrary app version and Android app store declaration.
        APPID,   // ADC App ID from adcolony.com
        zoneID
    );
}

public void PlayV4VC(string zoneID, bool prePopup, bool postPopup){

    if (AdColony.IsV4VCAvailable (zoneID)) {
        Debug.Log ("Video is avaiable!");
    } else {
        Debug.Log ("Video is NOT avaiable!");
    }
}

private void OnV4VCResult (bool success,string name, int amount){
    if (success) {
        Debug.Log ("Video watched!");
    } else {
        Debug.Log ("Failed.");
    }
}
```